# How to give arguments to a django-celery task without using admin panel?

Tags: python, django, django-celery

I Have developed a django app which will take backup,I want to do this with celery,thing is I need to know what are all the database celery have,so that I can get input from user and give that as arguments to a celery task instead of using admin panel options.
What I need to achieve:

```
def mycelerytask(hassomearguemnts):
    will do some work.
```

I need to give the arguments to that celery task programmatically instead of using admin panel's argument.

I want to achieve this with django orm.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the task using `delay` and pass arguments to it.

```
mycelerytask.delay(theargument)
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I think you are asking about inserting values from a django view.Yes you can give arguments by following this:
Take the form inputs from data and parse it into django-celery models like this.
This example is for passing arguments to PeriodictTask

```
from djcelery import PeriodicTask
def your_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
          form = yourform(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
                yourformfield = form.cleaned_data['yourformfield']
                periodic_task = PeriodicTask(name=task_name, task='yourapp.tasks.yourtaskname', args=yourformfield)
                peridoc_task.save()
Now you've created a periodic task without using the admin panel
```